# Fuzzy matching of words with phrases with ruby

Tags: ruby, fuzzy-search

I want to match a bunch of data with a short number of services

My data would look something like this

```
{"title" : "blorb",
"category" : "zurb"
"description" : "Massage is the manipulation of superficial and deeper layers of muscle and connective tissue using various techniques, to enhance function, aid in the healing process, decrease muscle reflex activity..."
}
```

and I have to match it with

> ["Swedish Massage", "Haircut"]

Clearly the `"Swedish Massage"` would be the winner, but running a benchmark shows that `"Haircut"` is:

```
require 'amatch'

arr = [:levenshtein_similar, :hamming_similar, :pair_distance_similar, :longest_subsequence_similar, :longest_substring_similar, :jaro_similar, :jarowinkler_similar]

arr.each do |method|
  ["Swedish Massage", "Haircut"].each do |sh|
    pp ">>> #{sh} matched with #{method.to_s}"
    pp sh.send(method, description)
  end
end and nil
```

result:

```
">>> Swedish Massage matched with jaro_similar"
# 0.5246896118183247
">>> Haircut matched with jaro_similar"
# 0.5353606789250354
">>> Swedish Massage matched with jarowinkler_similar"
# 0.5246896118183247
">>> Haircut matched with jarowinkler_similar"
# 0.5353606789250354
```

The rest of the indices are well below 0.1

What would be a better approach to solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Search is a constant battle between precision and recall. One thing you could try is splitting your input by words - this will result in a much stronger match on `Massage` but with the consequence of broadening out the result set. You will now find sentences returned with only words close to `Swedish`. You could then try to control that broadening by averaging the results for multiple words, using stop lists to avoid common words like `and`, boosts for finding tokens close to each other etc, but you will never see truly perfect results. If you're really interested in fine tuning this I recommend ElasticSearch - relatively easy to learn and powerful.